# Magento2 : new admin page controller issue

Tags: magento2, admin-controller

In order to add a new admin page, I follow [this tutorial](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ext-best-practices/extension-coding/example-module-adminpage.html) :

in the routes.xml, If I use as it is said the module name for id and frontname, I get an error when I try to access magento2 backend

routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="modulename" frontName="modulename">
            <module name="Mine_Modulename" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

error :

```
a:4:{i:0;s:227:"Warning: file_put_contents(/var/www/html/magento/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---365_STORE_RELATIONS): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/magento/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 663";i:1;s:4199:"#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'file_put_conten...', '/var/www/html/m...', 663, Array)
#1 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php(663): file_put_contents('/var/www/html/m...', '365_RESOLVED_ST...', 10)
#2 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php(179): Cm_Cache_Backend_File->_updateIdsTags(Array, Array, 'merge')
#3 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache/Core.php(390): Cm_Cache_Backend_File->save('a:2:{i:0;a:1:{i...', '365_RESOLVED_ST...', Array, NULL)
#4 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Core.php(74): Zend_Cache_Core->save('a:2:{i:0;a:1:{i...', 'RESOLVED_STORES...', Array, NULL, 8)
#5 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Adapter/Zend.php(47): Magento\Framework\Cache\Core->save('a:2:{i:0;a:1:{i...', 'RESOLVED_STORES...', Array, NULL)
#6 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/Bare.php(75): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Adapter\Zend->save('a:2:{i:0;a:1:{i...', 'resolved_stores...', Array, NULL)
#7 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/TagScope.php(49): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\Bare->save('a:2:{i:0;a:1:{i...', 'resolved_stores...', Array, NULL)
#8 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/Bare.php(75): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\TagScope->save('a:2:{i:0;a:1:{i...', 'resolved_stores...', Array, NULL)
#9 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/Bare.php(75): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\Bare->save('a:2:{i:0;a:1:{i...', 'resolved_stores...', Array, NULL)
#10 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Type/AccessProxy.php(85): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\Bare->save('a:2:{i:0;a:1:{i...', 'resolved_stores...', Array, NULL)
#11 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/Bare.php(75): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\AccessProxy->save('a:2:{i:0;a:1:{i...', 'resolved_stores...', Array, NULL)
#12 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/TagScope.php(49): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\Bare->save('a:2:{i:0;a:1:{i...', 'resolved_stores...', Array, NULL)
#13 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver.php(123): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\TagScope->save('a:2:{i:0;a:1:{i...', 'resolved_stores...', Array)
#14 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver.php(85): Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver->getStoresData()
#15 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreManager.php(154): Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver->getCurrentStoreId()
#16 /var/www/html/magento/var/generation/Magento/Store/Model/StoreManagerInterface/Proxy.php(119): Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager->getStore(NULL)
#17 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Resolver/Store.php(29): Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface\Proxy->getStore(NULL)
#18 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ScopeCodeResolver.php(49): Magento\Store\Model\Resolver\Store->getScope(NULL)
#19 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(79): Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeCodeResolver->resolve('stores', NULL)
#20 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Area/FrontNameResolver.php(96): Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('admin/url/use_c...', 'store')
#21 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Area/FrontNameResolver.php(79): Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver->isHostBackend()
#22 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/AreaList.php(73): Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver->getFrontName(true)
#23 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(130): Magento\Framework\App\AreaList->getCodeByFrontName('admin_toto')
#24 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#25 /var/www/html/magento/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#26 {main}";s:3:"url";s:23:"/magento/admin_toto";s:11:"script_name";s:18:"/magento/index.php";}
```

Any idea?

Thank you for your help

Comment: make sure you have write permissions on the `var` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Please give write permissions to `var` folder. You can run below command from Magento 2 root directory to give permissions.

```
chmod 775 -R var/
```

Comment: It is not safe to give write permissions for others to any Magento 2 folder. `775` permissions are enough, or `755` if it's a one-user ownership.

Comment: I checked but all files are 777 (local dev sverver)

Answer (score 0):

You have to give `<magento_root_folder>/var` write permissions for your Web server user / group. For more information, please follow [Magento 2 DevDocs guide for setting permissions](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html) in development and production.

Comment: if I change the id frontname of routes with controller nameinstead of module name, no more error (except I can not reach the created page, but this is another problem) ie not dur to permission

Comment: You can set your route ID as the module name, and then set the frontend name as whatever you want. Suppposing this router :
`<route id="vendor_module" frontName="tototest"><module name="Vendor_Module" /></route>`; If you created your controller in `app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index`, then you can acces your newly created page with this URL : http<s>://hostname.tld/magento/<admin_name>/tototest

Comment: Else, try to clean cache (if cache is enabled) by launching this command from your Magento root folder :
`php bin/magento cache:clean`
And refresh the page.